# The audience is invalid error in asp.net core authorization

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, identityserver3, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Identity server4 for authorization and then call the asp.net core api using the Breare access_token I get from the identity server. But I get the error error_description="The audience is invalid". I guess the potential error could be that in the identity server logs it states No endpoint entry found for request path: "/resource".

When I try to access http://localhost:idsport/resource, this does not exists.

Comment: [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44909827/934407) to a similar question might help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this error can mean everything. In my case it was using `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute for method.
Also incorrect injection additional services. Also Policies/roles/claims issues.

Comment: Using `AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken` attribute solves issues